# Sinch Receive Call

Tags: android, voip, sinch

I've been stuck on this for quite some time. I am using Sinch to establish calls.

This is the case:

1. Working Case: Both users have opened the **same activity**.

*User A* **--calls-->** *User B*

*User B* **<--receives call --** *User A*

User B receives the call.

2. Non-Working Case: User B doesn't have the app opened. I use **FCM** to send the notification of the call.

*User A* **--calls-->** *User B*

*User B* **<--receives call notification--** *User A*

*User B* **--opens-->** *Call Activity* -> **but there is no incoming call**

---

**Caller's Code:**

```
if (this.mCall == null) {
                mStatusInfo.setText("Calling...");
                this.mCall = this.mSinchClient.getCallClient().callUser(mRecipientId);
                this.mCall.addCallListener(new SinchCallListener());
                //Test
                String callId = this.mCall.getCallId();
                this.sendNotification(mTalkPath,mAuthor,mRecipient, callId);
}
```

**Receivers' Code:**

```
  private class SinchCallClientListener implements CallClientListener {
    @Override
    public void onIncomingCall(CallClient callClient, Call incomingCall) {
        //Pick up the mCall!
        mStatusInfo.setText("Incoming call...");
        mCall = incomingCall;
        mCall.addCallListener(new SinchCallListener());
        String metaData = String.format("%s, %s", mRecipient.getGender(), mRecipient.getBirthDate());
        mInfoText.setText(metaData);
    }
}
```

Is there any way to receive the call by using FCM? Maybe the callId can be a key to solve this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Check out this https://www.sinch.com/docs/voice/android/#pushnotificationssentviayourapplicationserver

That should give you the solution you need

Comment: I made it work. Thanks. It is easy to use it after all :)